# Why is this code so quick?

Tags: php, performance, require, file-exists

**EDIT**: This has been because of bug in my code (probably), after debugging and adding checking for correct response in my tests, test prove NO difference (what irks me a little), more in my own answer below.
*/EDIT*

Hello,

I've written myself a little CSS wrapper for SASS for PHP and programmed it to accept filename and possible flags before running (and possibly caching, if not flagged otherwise) my SASS file.

I've also conducted few test and version nr. **2** is something around **2x - 4x** slower than version nr. **1**, although version **1** has to run more code then version **2** (It does straight include from disk, rather than parsing URL first for flags).

I don't understand it why really and tests are somewhat too consistent to call it on a disk access overhead.

Here are speed tests:

> First - generate file, then - just require from cache
>   Version 1 total: **10.886** s avg: **10.886** ms/file first: **466.42** ms
>   Version 2 total: **21.235** s avg: **21.235** ms/file first: **14.54** ms
>
> Just require from cache
>   Version 1 total: **7.886** s  avg: **7.886** ms/file  first: **2.93** ms
>   Version 2 total: **21.657** s avg: **21.657** ms/file first: **6.98** ms
>
> Version with readfile instead of require
>   Version 1 run 1:  total: **7.915**    avg: **7.915** ms/file  first: **2.49** ms
>   Version 2 run 1:  total: **9.508**    avg: **9.508** ms/file  first: **3.23** ms
>   Version 1 run 2:  total: **1:17.137**     avg: **7.714** ms/file  first: **4.61** ms
>   Version 2 run 2:  total: **1:15.717**     avg: **7.572** ms/file  first: **2.69** ms
>   * - run 2 was **10,000** calls.

### Version 1

```
/* HELPER FUNCTIONS */
function is_option($opt) { global $url_options; return in_array($opt,$url_options); }
function fail($message) { echo $message; die(); }

//prepare options array
$options=array();

$url_options = @explode('_',basename($_GET['f']));
if (!is_array($url_options))
    { fail('Wrong parameters given (or parameter can\'t be accepted)'); }
$loadfile = array_shift($url_options);

if (!file_exists('source/'.$loadfile.'.sass'))
{
    if (!file_exists('source/'.$loadfile.'.scss'))
        fail('Wrong parameters given (file doesn\'t exist)');
    else
        $options['property_syntax']='scss';
}else{
    $options['property_syntax']='sass';
}

$src_file = 'source/'.$loadfile.'.'.$options['property_syntax'];
$css_file = 'cache/'.$loadfile.'.css';

if (file_exists($css_file) && !is_option('no-cache'))
{
    header('content-type: text/css');
    require($css_file);
    die(); //ALL OK, loaded from cache
}
```

### Version 2

```
//quick! load from cache if exists!
if (file_exists('cache/'.($cachefile=basename('/',$_GET['f']))))
{
    header('content-type: text/css');
    require('cache/'.$cachefile);
    die(); //ALL OK, loaded from cache
}

/* HELPER FUNCTIONS */
function is_option($opt) { global $url_options; return in_array($opt,$url_options); }
function fail($message) { echo $message; die(); }

//prepare options array
$options=array();

$url_options = @explode('_',basename($cachefile));
if (!is_array($url_options))
    { fail('Wrong parameters given (or parameter can\'t be accepted)'); }
$loadfile = array_shift($url_options);

if (!file_exists('source/'.$loadfile.'.sass'))
{
    if (!file_exists('source/'.$loadfile.'.scss'))
        fail('Wrong parameters given (file doesn\'t exist)');
    else
        $options['property_syntax']='scss';
}else{
    $options['property_syntax']='sass';
}

$src_file = 'source/'.$loadfile.'.'.$options['property_syntax'];
$css_file = 'cache/'.$loadfile.'.css';
```

I will go with version 1 probably, I would just like to understand WHY exactly v2 is slower, although it runs less code...

**EDIT:** Seems that `readfile` is a little faster than `require`, brought the two version to be statistically the same, although version **1** is still faster (but it's just 2 seconds for 1000 AND 10000 calls, so this might be just random disk usage)

Comment: What happens if you replace require with readfile? Require has to parse the cache file as a PHP script, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Emil: thank you, that brought a little speed up and brought both versions to almost the same speed, but still, I don't understand why with requires, version 1 is faster.

Comment: if this code doesn't implement conditional get, then it's just a waste of time

Comment: that's right next in the plan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the main difference was due to error in my code, pointed out by [ring0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/338904/ring0) (thank you).

After repairing the bug, editing the tests to show response in every *(n/10)th* case out of *n* iterations and running both tests parallel, results are these:

> **Results for Version 1 (with
>   require):**
>   Processed
>   **10000** times
> It took
>   **4:56.806**
>   [*1292676882*-*1292677179*]
> Average
>   time: **29.681** miliseconds
>
> **Results for Version 1 (with
>   readfile):**
>   Processed
>   **10000** times
> It took
>   **4:35.242**
>   [*1292677437*-*1292677712*]
> Average
>   time: **27.524** miliseconds
>
> **Results for Version 2 (with
>   require):**
>   Processed
>   **10000** times
> It took
>   **4:55.760**
>   [*1292676879*-*1292677175*]
> Average
>   time: **29.576**
>   miliseconds
>
> **Results for Version 2 (with
>   readfile):**
>   Processed
>   **10000** times
> It took
>   **4:32.336**
>   [*1292677433*-*1292677706*]
> Average
>   time: **27.234** miliseconds

**Graph:**
[image: Speeds for 10,000 iteration calls]

So, the new version/version 2 (the one, where the require/readfile is on top) is **faster** now, although not that significantly. I'll probably use that one, together with readfile enhancement (thanks to [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238978/emil-vikstrom)).

Thank you all, this is what happens if you do not test properly :)

This is what happens

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, "version 2 has to run more code" ?

Version 2 is checking the cache first and skipping all the rest if it finds the cached file.

Of course, it is also completely ignoring all the "URL options".

Comment: That was just misplaced numbers - due to testing in reversered order - i test version1 with `test2.php` and version 2 with `test1.php`, just a mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a bug in

```
  if (file_exists('cache/'.($cachefile=basename('/',$_GET['f']))))
```

either

- there is a type and `explode` wanted to be used instead
- or `basename` is not used as it should - i.e. `basename($_GET['f'])` instead of `basename('/', $_GET['f'])`

Therefore the `$cachefile` is blank, the `if` is always *true* and the `require` applies to the `cache` directory.

Comment: I thought that that might be it! But, it seems that the only result is, that it deleted any speed bump gaind by using `readfile` against `require`, so I'm conducting more tests with actual responses.